# subAppendix is out of the Appendices

Tags: appendices

I used

```
\begin{appendices}
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\theequation{\thesection\arabic{equation}}

\setcounter{figure}{0}
    \section{Independent Testing}
\end{appendices}
```

Then `Appendix A` is out of the `Appendices` as following. How to put `Appendix A` into the `Appendices` i.e `+Appendices => Appendix A`.

I tried to use `\subsection{Independent Testing}`, it becomes `.1 Independent Testing` which is unexpected.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: I am assuming you are using the documentclass* `article` *here.*

Your problem seems to be that you want a clear difference in the table of contents between the start of the appendices and an appendix section.

To format the table of content the way you want you would need to redefine quite some parts of the `appendices` [package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/appendix/appendix.pdf). I personally don't have the know-how on that part, but I can offer other solutions to your problem.

You can tell the appendices package to not add the phantom section "Appendices" to your table of contents by **not** including the command `\addappheadtotoc` in your document.

Alternatively you could use the command `\noappendicestocpagenum` before you start the appendices environment to remove the number behind the phantom section.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{appendix}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Regular Section}
\subsection{Regular Subsection}
\newpage

\noappendicestocpagenum %Remove the page number from the table of contents header
\begin{appendices}
\addappheadtotoc %Comment this line to remove the Appendices header entirely

\section{Appendix Section}
\subsection{Appendix Subsection}

\section{Another Appendix Section}
\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image: Table of Contents with Appendices]